# MySQL fallback query if no results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this query that selects 10 related videos to the given video from `videos` table. I want `always to have 10 results` so if this query fails to get results or there are less than 10 results another query with less where conditions will be executed. I was counting the rows in `php` before, making another query and merging the results. It was so slow and the code got too long. I know it is better and faster to do in SQL. I'm using `PDO` with `php`.

How can I combine them?

First query (main one):

```
select * from videos
where FROM_UNIXTIME(published) BETWEEN
DATE_SUB(FROM_UNIXTIME(:published), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
AND DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(:published), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
and video_name != :video_name
ORDER BY RAND() limit 10";
```

Second query(fallback):

```
select * from videos ORDER BY RAND() limit 10
```

Comment: what happens if you end up with `select * from foo` and still get <10 results? can't get any simpler than that.

Comment: the idea is that in 90% of the cases there will be related videos because the table with have more than 3000 rows. If not I will execute the fallback query. But first the main query will be executed.

Comment: Were you able to identify which part specifically made it "so slow"?

Comment: And the second `ORDER BY RAND()` might just as easily deliver you one you got from your previous query

Comment: can't use indexes on that query, since you're converting your timestamps **ON THE FLY** from datetimes to unix timestamps. you can compare dates directly, with indexes. `published BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(:published - INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(:published + INTERVAL 6 month`). this converts your two boundary values **ONCE** and compares against the unix stamps in your table, instead of converting EVERY SINGLE timestamp in the table.

Comment: IF the first query has no results the second query is needed to execute. I must count rows and etc. this makes it so slow @PatrickQ

Comment: `SELECT long query LIMIT 10 UNION short query LIMIT 10` then only fetch 10 rows in PHP.

Comment: I have covered that in php. @RiggsFolly I want to do now everything in SQL

Comment: Is it really that easy?? @AbraCadaver

Comment: So the idea is to get  20 rows(in most of cases) and display only 10 right? @AbraCadaver

Comment: Yes.  If you show how you fetch I can put it in an answer.

Comment: what about `SELECT * FROM (SELECT long UNION SELECT short) t ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10` - no PHP needed in that case.

Comment: SELECT ... and SELECT ... means first and second query right?? this will show always 10 results? right? @mitkosoft

Comment: @rexhin, it means to combine both queries and to do parent SELECT over that result again with LIMIT 10.

Comment: Can you post it as an answer please? @mitkosoft

Comment: I will make the modifications @MarcB thank you

Comment: Can you explain it better please. @MarcB why your query is better?

Comment: from_unixtime() creates datetime values on-the-fly, which means that indexes (if any) on those time value fields can NOT be used for filtering records in the where clause. that means you're forcing a full-table scan every time you run this query, which is highly inefficient.

Comment: Thank you. I made the changes you told. So what do you think is better? using paret select unions and inner selects and joins vs counting rows in php and making the decisions there if we need a new query or not? most of the cases the main query will return 10 results. I need to make a decision @MarcB

Comment: I can't answer that. you need to benchmark various options and determine which is best in your particular case. but in general, anything you do that prevents indexes from being used is a BAD thing and should be avoided like the plague.

Comment: Hey your query is not working. I get no results. my old query works. `published` is stored as unix timestamp in the table @MarcB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine them with `UNION` and to do "parent" `SELECT` again with `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM videos
    WHERE
        FROM_UNIXTIME(published) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(FROM_UNIXTIME(: published), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
        AND DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(: published),INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
        AND video_name != : video_name
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10

    UNION

    SELECT * FROM videos
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
) t
LIMIT 10
```

This will give you 10 records at the end without need of any PHP logic. Not sure what will be performance with such SQL.

Comment: Just curious, is the `t` needed?

Comment: It will be  faster than my previous code where I was mixing SQL and php. I'm almost sure.

Comment: @AbraCadaver, you kidding me, right? :) Every derived table must have its own alias.

Comment: @rexhin, just removed outside `ORDER BY RAND()` in order to get first 10 records if they all are from first statement.

Comment: @rexhin I'm almost sure that it will _not_ be faster. You said that 90% of the time the first query will be enough to produce 10 results, right? So why would it be faster to _always_ also do the second query. As MarcB pointed out in the initial comments, you should look into rewriting your clauses.

Comment: so you are saying that is better to have them separated. like before? and check the results in php? @PatrickQ

Comment: @rexhin Try it both ways and find out for yourself.  There's really only one way to know what's best for your specific situation.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a `UNION` on both `SELECT` queries with the more specific one first.  Then you are guaranteed to have between 10 and 20 rows (so long as there are at least 10 rows in the table) and you can just fetch the first 10 from the result.  It will either be 10 specific ones, 10 default ones or a mix with the specific ones listed first:

```
SELECT * FROM videos
    WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(published) BETWEEN
    DATE_SUB(FROM_UNIXTIME(:published), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND
    DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(:published), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND
    video_name != :video_name
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10

UNION

SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
```

You can also `SELECT` from a sub-`SELECT` query that selects 10 specific ones, 10 default ones and then selects the first 10 of those:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT * FROM videos
        WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(published) BETWEEN
        DATE_SUB(FROM_UNIXTIME(:published), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND
        DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(:published), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND
        video_name != :video_name
        ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10

    UNION

    SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10) temporary

LIMIT 10
```

I have no idea how much faster these will be but it's all in SQL.

Comment: can you check @mitkosoft comment please. That gives only 10 I think??